# How can i disable all the"submit" buttons inside my asp.net mvc 3 using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to write a script that disable all the submit buttons when the user click on them, i wrote the following Jquery script that will be avilable on all the views , but it did not work:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[type=submit]").click({
        this.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    });
})
```

So what is wrong wiht my code?
BR

Comment: Are you wanting to only disable the specific button when you  click on it or when you click on one button it disable all buttons?

Comment: You got enough answers, but one more way is the `:submit` selector: `$(":submit").click({
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
         this.disabled = true;
    });
});
```

If the submit button is submitting a form, you will have to prevent the default action that will reload the page:

```
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 - I was actually going to point out that sometimes modifying the attribute doesn't do the job. I've had much better success in my own code using the .prop method like this. If the OP still continues to have trouble, I highly recommend the approach that uses the property.

Comment: Agreed. If I could +1 it again I would.

Comment: it worked well ,, but this raised a problem in my application as i have some "submit" buttons to perform search functionality ,, and what is happening is that the seach button will be disabled and the user will have to refresh the page to perform another search. so is there a way to re-enable the search buttons after receiving the search results. thanks

Comment: Yes there is, but that would require more code, and is probably more suited for a new question, especially if that search function is ajax based, but a simple fix would be to add a class to the buttons you'd like this to work on, and use that as the selector instead of targeting all the submit buttons.

Comment: To enable a button you only do `$(yourButton).prop('disabled', false);`, but you have to do that inside the search function when the result is ready, and `this` will no longer be in scope, so you'd need a way to target the element, or just enable all buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // if you want to disable all buttons on the form do the following
    // $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**Edit:**

adeneo is correct. It would probably be a good idea to use the `prop()` method. I have personally never had issues with disabling via `attr('disabled', 'disabled')`, but I have heard people mention it before.

However, this jquery forum post on [please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6) might more explain the reason why people are having issues with disabling when using the attr() method. They are most likely setting it to true instead of disabled.

Comment: the visual studio raised the following error "Expected ':'" on $(this). so how i can fix it?

Comment: Try putting quotes around the `type=submit` so it's `type='submit'` I usually see single quotes around the right side of the =, so that may **(or may not be)** be throwing it off. Other than this slight possible issue, I see nothing else that could possibly be wrong with this.

Comment: It should be pretty obvious that most of the answers are missing the function call on the click handler, like so : `element.click(function() {...});`

Comment: adeneo you are correct. I copied his and did not notice that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit({
        $("input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        return true;
    });
});
```

The above would be a better way to achieve what you intend to do. If you insist on getting your code to work, remove the `:` before `input` in the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to disable all of the buttons, but the "this" keyword only references the item that caused the event to be thrown, so you need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click({
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled","disabled");

    });
});
```

Comment: no i mean to disable all the buttons once the user clicks on them !! thanks

Comment: That's what this does. It disables all of the submit buttons once the user clicks on one of them. Did I miss something in your above comment? I'm not sure whether you mean "No, this doesn't solve my problem" or "No, you understood what I meant".

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script doesn't work is because `this` is referring to the HTML element, not the jQuery object. You need to wrap it in a jQuery object to run functions such as `attr` on it:

```
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Additionally, if you want to disable **all** submit buttons then you need to perform a new selection and disable them all. This code should do what you want:

```
// Passing a function to $ will run it on document ready
$(function () {
    $("input[type=submit]").click({
        // Select all submit inputs and disable them
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

All submit buttons should now be disabled when one is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try without ":" in input selector and use $(this).

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
})
```

FYI - I have used shorthand syntax for $(document).ready.

Comment: but that compilar raised an error the it is expecting identifier or string on the "this".

Comment: I updated above code to fix the error. I know you already found the answer but just wanted to correct the code.